# Is this a smooth immersion of $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This has to be a smooth immersion according to John Lee's book Introduction to smooth manifolds, page 78. I compute the rank of the Jacobian matrix of the map X in an arbitrary point $(u_o,v_o)$ but after the calculations, I just showed that $\text{rank}(J(X))=1$ or $2$. It has to be $2$! I really need help. It is self-study - manifolds for about 3 years. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: At least you should write down what you got for $J(X)$.

Comment: As the image of the map is the standard torus of revolution, this is a smooth map. I guess you maybe just made a mistake in your calculation, if you post it here we can check it.

Comment: I will try to write it in tex later, unfortunately it is a bit difficult for me. I am a beginner. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jacobian matrix is
$$
2\pi\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin(2\pi u)\cos(2\pi v) & -\sin(2\pi u)\sin(2\pi v)&\cos(2\pi u)\\
-(2 + \cos(2\pi u))\sin(2\pi v) & (2+\cos(2\pi u))\cos(2\pi v) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(or maybe it's the transpose; I can never remember).
We split into cases, depending on whether $\cos(2\pi u)= 0$.

If $\cos(2\pi u) = 0$, then $\sin(2\pi u) = \pm 1$. This reduces the matrix to
$$
2\pi\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
\pm\cos(2\pi v) & \pm\sin(2\pi v)&0\\
-2\sin(2\pi v) & 2\cos(2\pi v) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(where the $\pm$ stands for the same sign in both places). The determinant of the left $2\times 2$ submatrix is
$$
(4\pi^2)\cdot(\pm2\cos^2(2\pi v)\pm 2\sin^2(2\pi v)) = 4\pi^2\cdot (\pm2)\neq 0
$$
which means that the first two columns are linearly independent, and the matrix has rank 2.

If $\cos(2\pi u)\neq 0$, then for the rank to be $1$, the second component of all the  columns must be $0$. But $(2+\cos(2\pi u))\neq 0$, and $\sin(2\pi v)$ and $\cos(2\pi v)$ can't both be zero. So the rank must be 2.

Comment: It is perfect! Thank you i had a mistake in the calculations. I understand now! Thank you! Bless you!

Comment: It's the transpose. I just go to linear algebra to remember which. Jacobian is matrix representation of a linear map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, so it should be $m\times n$ matrix. But, this doesn't really tell you how to write it, so I prefer this other way. If you look at $F = (f_1,\ldots, f_m)$, each component function $f_i$ has its gradient $\nabla f_i$, which is a vector-row (as it should be, by the same linear algebra convention as for Jacobian). So, Jacobian is just a column of those gradients. Hopefully, I didn't bore you with this :)

Comment: @Ennar That sounds reasonable. Although, for many cases (like this one) it's not really relevant. And for more advanced applications I personally prefer the index notation $J^i{}_j=\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j}=\partial_j f^i$ anyways. And I remember fine which indices are upper and which are lower. The place I always mix up is when translating double-indexed quantities back into matrices.